# Social Club Store not loading

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I've recently purchased GTA V on Steam. I was playing the game and I had decided that I wanted to buy in-game money (with real money). However, when I clicked the checkout button I got stuck with a small loading circle which then promptly froze.

Is there any way to get it working again?